# How to fix element inside slant box to normal positioning or straight

Tags: html, css

How to fix element inside slant box to normal positioning or straight line, please check the info below because when i entered element for example image the word is slant as well i want to make it straight what we need to do ?

```
.box.side {
  margin-top: 48vh;
  height: 48vh;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slope {
  margin: 0 -100px;
  transform-origin: right center;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="box side slope">
      <h1> sample </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: checkinfo]

Answer (score 0):

use a pseudo element after something just like this:

```css
.slope {
  background: black;
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.slope::after { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
}

.slope h1{
  color:#fff;
  float:right;
}
```

In this way all the content inside the div wont tilt to -2deg